# Show DatePicker when link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a link and I would like to show a date picker when I click it:

```
$('body').on("click", ".date-link", function (e) {
    /*
    $("#daterange").dialog("option", "position",
           {
               my: "left top",
               at: "left bottom",
               of: e,
           });

    $("#daterange").dialog('open');
    */

    $(e).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
            changeCalendarDate(dateText);
        },
        onClose: function (dateText) {
        }
    });

    $("#filter").dialog('close');
});
```

I would also like it to auto close when any document element is clicked unless the user chooses a date wherein it will autoclose.

Thanks

Comment: In the code above, you are trying to call [`.datepicker()`](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker) on the event object. It should be called on a jQuery object representing the DOM element that should trigger it (usually an input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up your datepicker instance outside of the click handler. Then when the link is clicked, just call `.datepicker('show')` on the element where the datepicker was set up.

Here is a simplified example:

**HTML**

```
<input id="date" />
<a href="#" class="date-link">Date Link</a>
```

**JS**

```
$("#date").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        changeCalendarDate(dateText);
    }
});

$('.date-link').on('click', function(e) {
    // Do not follow link
    e.preventDefault();
    // Show the datepicker
    $('#date').datepicker('show');
});

function changeCalendarDate(dateText) {
    // Process date
    console.log(dateText);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JYqqg/)**